# Modifying instance variable in a proc in cucumber Around hook

Tags: ruby, cucumber

When using cucumber, I reference an instance variable used in a step definition e.g.

```
Given /^I have an instance variable in my step$/ do
  @person.should_not be_nil
end
```

With a getter in my env.rb using the Before hook e.g.

```
class Person
  def be_happy
    puts "smiling"
  end
end

person = Person.new

Before do
  @person = person
end
```

All good so far ...

But if I want to use an Around hook instead, my understanding is that it yields a proc from which I can call the block that was in the step e.g.

```
Around do |scenario, block|
  @person = person
  block.call
end
```

But this fails, as @person is nil. Is this because @person is instantiated when the proc is created, and thus cannot be modified. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with @person?

Comment: Where @person is normally a single object, it will be used as part of a block e.g.

@people.each |person|
  @person = person
  block.call
end

Comment: or in other words, I want to reuse the same block of code defined in the step on each of the persons in an array of people ... instead of just one person. So for each step, it gets iterated over n times where n is the size of the people array ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions come to mind

**Using a World**

Try using [World](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/A-Whole-New-World), perhaps with something like this in env.rb:

```
class Person
  def be_happy
    puts "smiling"
  end
end

World do
  Person.new
end

Around do |scenario, block|
  block.call
end
```

And your step def should then do something more like:

```
Given /^I have an instance variable in my step$/ do
  be_happy.should eql("smiling")
end
```

With this approach, you get a branch new Person every scenario, which is probably a good thing.

**Using a Constant**
In the event you don't want a brand new Person for every scenario, just use a constant, perhaps like so:

```
class Person
  def be_happy
    "smiling"
  end
end

MyPerson = Person.new

Around do |scenario, block|
  block.call
end
```

with step def like so:

```
Given /^I have an instance variable in my step$/ do
  MyPerson.be_happy.should eql("smiling")
end
```